# JQuery Append to SELECT not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to append an item to my jquery select like so...

http://jsfiddle.net/5sWCp/

but it doesn't appear to be working. could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? If it's at all relevant I'm testing on Chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't select jQuery in jsFiddle, you were using MooTools so it is not surprising that your jsfiddle doesn't work.

I've fixed it here: http://jsfiddle.net/5sWCp/1/

Also notice that you should use `$("<option>").attr("value", msg)` and not `$("option").attr("value", msg)` as you did in your initial fiddle. So here's the final version:

```
function append(msg) {
    $('<option/>')
        .attr('value', msg)
        .text(msg)
        .appendTo('#n');
}

append('test');
```